# MySQL get records beetween tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've got a big problem in my hands, I have the following SQL structure, where the **contracts** tables are dinamically generated, with random names, like **_xyz**, **_xxx**, etc:

```
CREATE TABLE contract_xyz(
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
 );
CREATE TABLE contract_events(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_contract INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    table_contract VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO contract_xyz (id,created_at) VALUES (1,'2016-11-01');
INSERT INTO contract_xyz (id,created_at) VALUES (2,'2016-10-21');
INSERT INTO contract_xyz (id,created_at) VALUES (3,'2016-11-04');
INSERT INTO contract_events(id,id_contract,table_contract,created_at) VALUES (1,1,'contract_xyz','2016-11-03');
INSERT INTO contract_events(id,id_contract,table_contract,created_at) VALUES (2,3,'contract_xyz','2016-11-04');
```

Each contract can have his own events. I need to solve the following issue:

**Get all contracts that don't have new events in 2 days, or don't have any event at all, and was created over 2 days ago.**

I've tried with **LET JOIN** but it wasn't the correct result. The nearest I get was the following query:

```
SELECT `contract_xyz`.*
FROM `contract_xyz`
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
         FROM `contract_events`
         WHERE
           `contract_events`.id_contract = `contract_xyz`.id AND `contract_events`.table_contract = 'contract_xyz'
           AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `contract_events`.created_at) >= 2
         ORDER BY `contract_events`.created_at DESC
         LIMIT 1)
  OR (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM `contract_events`
                 WHERE `contract_events`.id_contract = `contract_xyz`.id AND
                       `contract_events`.table_contract = 'contract_xyz') AND
      DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `contract_xyz`.created_at) >= 2);
```

But I still can't find the contracts that doesn't have any events, and was created over 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a subquery with the max event date for each contract. I would left join the contracts table on this subquery. You can filter based on the max event date and the created date fields to achieve the expected outcome:

```
select c.*
from contract_xyz c
left join 
    (select id_contract,
           max(created_at) max_event_date
     from contract_events
     group by id_contract) t on c.id-t.id_contract
 where
     DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t.max_event_date) >= 2
     or (t.max_event_date is null and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), c.created_at) >= 2)
```

Alternatively, you do not use a subquery, but join the 2 tables directly with group by and do the filtering in the `having` clause.

Comment: Perfect! Totally worked! I was able to get all contracts that don't have events , and is more than 2 days old, and all contracts that have events and the newest event is more than 2 days old. Thanks @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` with an `ON` condition could help here:

```
select c.id, c.created_at,count(e.id) as contract_events_less_than_2_days_old
from contract_xyz c
left outer join contract_events e on e.id_contract = c.id 
                                 and e.table_contract = 'contract_xyz' 
                                 and e.created_at > now() - interval 2 day
where c.created_at < now() - interval 2 day
and e.id is null
group by c.id, c.created_at;
```

If you have any control over it I would advise against dynamically-generated table names!